# Withdraw funds from contract

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, testing, smart-contract-wallets, mocha

I made the following withdraw function in my smart contract:

```
function withdraw() public onlyOwner
{
    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("");    
}
```

I call this function in my mocha test as follows:

```
instance = await DataContract.deployed();
user1 = accounts[0];
await instance.withdraw({from:user1});
```

However, the call to the withdraw function gives the following error:

Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

Anyone has any idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: What happens if you remove `onlyOwner`?

Comment: I get the same error message if I remove OnlyOwner.

Comment: Is the contract deployed?

Comment: Yes, on ganache.